# List all S3-files parsed by AWS Glue from a table using the AWS Python SDK boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk, aws-glue

I tried to find a way through the [Glue API docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_table), but there is no attribute or method related to the functions `get_table(**kwargs)` or `get_tables(**kwargs)`.

I imagine something akin to the following (pseudo-)code:

```
client = boto3.client('glue')
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_tables')
for response in paginator.paginate(DatabaseName=db_input_shared):
    for table in response['TableList']:
        files = table["files"]  # NOTE: the keyword "files" is invented
        # Do something else
        ...
```

As far as I can see from the docs, the `table` from the `reponse["TableList"]` should be a dictionary; yet none of its keys seem to give access to the files stored in it.

Comment: Can you clarify which files? Those in s3 that glue parses?

Comment: Yes @Marcin, exactly. I'm going to add this information to the OP.

Comment: I don't you can do this. Can yo find such info in AWS Console?

Comment: I would like to get a list of all files within a Glue table, in order to check against another list of files. This way, I'd be able to check whether a particular file lives in a Glue table or not. How would you do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are after. Maybe some screenshot from Glue console showing which "files" are you after would help to clarify that.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I'm thinking to simple about this, and perhaps it does not work that way with Glue. It's like this: 1) I have a list of uploaded filepaths in S3, 2) I have a table in Glue, 3) I want to check whether any of the files in 1) are present in 2)

Comment: Glue parses a folder in S3 and any files stored there. I'm not aware of it to discriminate between actual files in S3.

Comment: I had to use `awswrangler`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was using [awswrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler).

The following functions checks all `AWS Glue` Tables within a database for a specific list of *recently uploaded files*. Whenever the filename matches, it is going to yield the associated table dictionary. These yielded tables are those which have been recently updated.

```
def _yield_recently_updated_glue_tables(upload_path_list: List[str],
                                        db_name: str) -> Union(dict, None):
    """Check which tables have been updated recently.

    Args:
        upload_path_list (List[str]): contains all S3-filepaths of recently uploaded files
        db_name (str): name of the AWS Glue database

    Yields:
        Union(dict, None): AWS Glue table dictionaries recently updated
    """
    client = boto3.client('glue')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('get_tables')
    for response in paginator.paginate(DatabaseName=db_name):
        for table_dict in response['TableList']:
            table_name = table_dict['Name']
            s3_bucket_path = awswrangler.catalog.get_table_location(
                database=db_name, table=table_name)
            s3_filepaths = list(
                awswrangler.s3.describe_objects(s3_bucket_path).keys())
            table_was_updated = False
            for upload_file in upload_path_list:
                if upload_file in s3_filepaths:
                    table_was_updated = True
                    break
            if table_was_updated:
                yield table_dict
```